# Servlet declarative security

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, servlets

For Servlet security, I read that in web.xml we can declare

```
<auth-constraints> and <user-data-constraint>
```

for turning on the SSL and for authentication purposes. But so far I personally haven't seen any of these declarations in real life web.xml's (apps running on Tomcat, Glassfish)

So I wonder what are the substitute ways of achieving these goals? and which way is preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends strongly on the used application server, but in general there is no way to make application server to expose the application using SSL without enabling it on the level of the AS (not the deployment descriptor).

For instance for Tomcat, the SSL connector (default port 8443) has to be enabled in `server.xml`. You may then use Apache (httpd) as a reverse proxy using `mod_proxy` or `mod_jk`.

In the code you may use `ServletFilter` to intercept all the requests and if the communication is not on top of SSL, you may redirect the user to some login page.

Comment: For example using Tomcat how can I seton/off Https without decalring anything in web.xml

Comment: https = port 443. Assuming you are running it on a Unix based system, only root can run application listening on ports lower than 1024. So the first option is to modify the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml`. And change the port of ssl connector to 443 and run the tomcat as root. 
Other option is to use a reverse proxy.

Comment: IIRC, the keystore file has to be generated and the connector should contain the path to this keystore file. You may find useful the following link http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

First you declare the roles, can do it with annotation or in web.xml:

```
@DeclareRoles("userRole")
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
}
```

Then you add `<security-constraint>`  to your `web.xml`:

```
  <security-constraint>
        <display-name>SecurityConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>SomeServlet</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/some_servlet</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>userRole</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
             <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    </login-config>
```

The `<url-pattern>` is the pattern to protect.

For SSL you put `CONFIDENTIAL` in `<transport-guarantee>`

Comment: tnx but my question was more how to turn on HTTPS, set authentication mode without touching to web.xml for instance in tomcat and glassfish